# Angular2 ng2-Bootstrap collapse add transition/animation

Tags: angular, ng2-bootstrap

I'm using this
https://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/#/collapse
and I would like to add an animation/transition on height 0 - auto but we all know that you can't add transition on height auto.
I would like to add a slideToggle efect with a duration on it.
Tried to look for a solution for over 3 days...

Is there a known solution for this?

Answer (score 11):

Animation is coming soon in `ng2-bootstrap`. You just need to wait a bit.

- https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap/blob/v1.1.1/components/collapse/collapse.directive.ts#L23

1) Today you can leverage as workaround the following:

```typescript
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
           (click)="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed">Toggle collapse
      </button>
      <div (collapsed)="setHeight(el, 0)"
           (expanded)="setHeight(el, 0);setHeight(el, el.scrollHeight)"
           [collapse]="isCollapsed"
           class="card card-block card-header block"  #el>
        <div class="well well-lg">Some content</div>
      </div>
  `,
  styles: [`
    .block {
      display: block !important;
      overflow: hidden !important;
      -webkit-transition: height .5s;
      transition: height .5s;
    }
  `]
})
export class App {
  isCollapsed: boolean = true;

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer) { }

  setHeight(el, height) {
    this.renderer.setElementStyle(el, 'height', height + 'px');
  }
}
```

See also a working **[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/JiMAPlYmmEZFjjqxenc3?p=preview)**

2) Without the `CollapseDirective` directive you can do it like this

```typescript
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
      (click)="height = height ? 0 : el.scrollHeight">Toggle collapse
    </button>

    <div       
      class="card card-block card-header block" [style.height]="height + 'px'" #el> 
      <div class="well well-lg">Some content</div>
    </div>
  `,
  styles: [`
    .block {
      overflow: hidden;
      -webkit-transition: height .5s;
      transition: height .5s;
    }
  `]
})
export class App {
  height = 0;
}
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/VLQ4Izy4VBZdm71UcRWZ?p=preview)**

Comment: While we are waiting for the upgrade, this works for me!

Comment: As of today, does anyone know if animation landed in ng2-bootstrap? Actually, even better, since which version did they land, if any? Could not figure out from their issue https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap/issues/355. Thanks to anyone who can shed a light

Comment: Thanks! The alternative without the collapseDirective works great! Especially for those who don't want to be tied to angular bootstrap

Comment: @yurzui, the first Plunker does not seem to work anymore.